# New GPU power supply woes (ASUS GT640 + HP XW4600)

Tags: power-supply, gpu, pci-express

I have a new GPU - ASUS Geforce GT640 - which doesn't require (or have connector) for separate power supply, however when plugged into a HP XW4600 the machine fails to boot - 4 beeps in a cycle.

I didn't spec this, the person that did assumed the PSU wasn't up to it, so purchased a 750W replacement, however this doesn't make any difference.

The XW4600 Mainboard has printed on: SLOT2 PCIe2 x16 75w + 75w, so I'm guessing the PCIe bus can't deliver enough power to the GPU - is there any workaround for this? 
Could the fan connector be disconnected and reconnected to some sort of PSU adapter rather than from the BUS?

Comment: Is there a molex connector somewhere on the motherboard?

Comment: Something is wrong with the premise of your question. The GT460 is a 150W (or so) monster, requiring two 6-pin power connectors.

Comment: David is right, the DEFAULT requirements for all GTX460 is 2x 6pin PCI-E Power Connectors. Either you don't have a GTX460 or you haven't spotted the connectors.

Comment: sorry I have transposed the full text statement the card is (as the title states) a GT640

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but this isn't a power problem, HP crippled the bios in these and nvidia cards newer than the 5xx series will not post.

Comment: That's an interesting claim. If you could share some evidence or at least citation, that would be great.